# Change Text on Button with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I just started with ASP.NET and C# a week ago and its going the right way. At my journey I ran in to a problem with changing the Box Label when clicking on it.

I found some examples on this site and tried to implement it, but somehow it is not working.

My head looks like:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $('button').click(function () {
          $(this).text(function (i, old) {
              return old == '+' ? '-' : '+';
          });
      });

  </script> 
</head>
```

and my body looks like:

```
<body>

        <button>+</button>

</body>
```

But this button is not changing from + to - when im clicking on it.

I tried to put on jsfiddle, and here it is working.

http://jsfiddle.net/fVpkm/114/

can you tell me what is wrong with my very simple form?

Your Sincerely

KP

Comment: At my side your fiddle works...Which browser you use?

Comment: Working just perfectly!

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your code with $(document).ready(function(){ });

Comment: Cheers. I wrapped my code with $(document).ready(function(){ }); as you suggested s. alam, and now its working. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @s.alem could you maybe explain me why that worked?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. If you have further questions, you can ask as a comment to that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle, on the left side, it says onDomready. So you don't have to use document.ready. But in the real code, you should wait for the dom to load.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('button').click(function () {
          $(this).text(function (i, old) {
              return old == '+' ? '-' : '+';
          });
      });
});
  </script> 
</head>
```

Comment: ahh. Great. Thanks! Now I am going to continue to throw myself at it again and again!

Comment: I made it work on my webpage now. But I have a problem with a login button that is also a <button ....> So when I click on this it changes the name. Can I somehow add that function to a ID?

Comment: Because if I add another button that function shouldnt be executed when pushing that button. If you understand my question?

Comment: You should add id or class attribute to your button. <button id="plusMinus">... Than instead of $("button"), call it with $("#plusMinus")...

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Ashish, your fiddle works perfectly. The only problem here would be the correct declaration.

Try wrapping the script in the DOM load event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* code here */
}
```